# Level Three Tikz Pictures in a row

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, horizontal-alignment

I have made the attached picture in tikz. But I cannot level three figures at the same level of the graphs. I want the block should be at zero level of the other two graphs. The code of the figure is also attached if someone can help.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\pgfplotsset{every tick label/.append style={font=\huge}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,transform shape]
      \begin{axis}[
    axis lines = middle,
    xmin = 0,
    xmax = 1.1,
    ymin = -1.25,
    ymax = 1.25,
    xtick = {0,0.5,1},
    ytick = {-1,0,1},
    axis line style = thick,
    xlabel style={right},
    % xlabel style={at=(current axis.right of origin), anchor=west},
    xlabel={\huge $t$},
    ylabel style={above},
    % ylabel style={at=(current axis.above origin), anchor=south},
    ylabel={\huge $u(t)$},
    extra y ticks = {0},
    % extra x ticks = {0},
    yticklabel style={
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        /pgf/number format/precision=4
    },
    x post scale=1.2,
    y post scale=1.2,
    clip=false
]
\addplot [
    domain=0:1,
    samples=300,
    line width = 2pt, blue
] {sin(deg(2*pi*x))};
\addplot [
    domain=0:1,
    samples=300,
    line width = 2pt, blue
] {sin(deg(2*pi*(x))))};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, fill=gray!30, rectangle, 
    minimum height=3em, minimum width=6em]
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [block] (controller) {$LTI$};
    \draw [-Latex] (controller) -- node [midway, above] {$y(t)$} (2,0);
    \draw [-Latex] (-2,0) -- node [midway, above] {$u(t)$} (controller);  
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,transform shape]
      \begin{axis}[
    axis lines = middle,
    xmin = 0,
    xmax = 1.1,
    ymin = -2,
    ymax = 2,
    xtick = {0,0.5,1},
    ytick = {-1.5,0,1.5},
    axis line style = thick,
    xlabel style = {right},
    % xlabel style={at=(current axis.right of origin), anchor=west},
    xlabel={\huge $t$},
    % ylabel style={at=(current axis.above origin), anchor=south},
    ylabel style={above},
    ylabel={\huge $y(t)$},
    extra y ticks = {0},
    % extra x ticks = {0},
    yticklabel style={
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        /pgf/number format/precision=4
    },
    x post scale=1.2,
    y post scale=1.2,
    clip=false
]
\addplot [
    domain=0:1,
    samples=300,
    line width = 2pt, blue
] {sin(deg(2*pi*x))};
\addplot [
    domain=0:1,
    samples=300,
    line width = 2pt, red
] {1.5*sin(deg(2*pi*(x+(1/4))))};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{figure}
```

[image: picture]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `baseline=...` to each `tikzpicture` as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\pgfplotsset{every tick label/.append style={font=\huge}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center), % <----
    scale=0.5,transform shape]
      \begin{axis}[
    axis lines = middle,
    xmin = 0,
    xmax = 1.1,
    ymin = -1.25,
    ymax = 1.25,
    xtick = {0,0.5,1},
    ytick = {-1,0,1},
    axis line style = thick,
    xlabel style={right},
    % xlabel style={at=(current axis.right of origin), anchor=west},
    xlabel={\huge $t$},
    ylabel style={above},
    % ylabel style={at=(current axis.above origin), anchor=south},
    ylabel={\huge $u(t)$},
    extra y ticks = {0},
    % extra x ticks = {0},
    yticklabel style={
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        /pgf/number format/precision=4
    },
    x post scale=1.2,
    y post scale=1.2,
    clip=false
]
\addplot [
    domain=0:1,
    samples=300,
    line width = 2pt, blue
] {sin(deg(2*pi*x))};
\addplot [
    domain=0:1,
    samples=300,
    line width = 2pt, blue
] {sin(deg(2*pi*(x))))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, fill=gray!30, rectangle,
    minimum height=3em, minimum width=6em]
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=1.4ex] current bounding box.center)}] % <----
    \node [block] (controller) {$LTI$};
    \draw [-Latex] (controller) -- node [midway, above] {$y(t)$} (2,0);
    \draw [-Latex] (-2,0) -- node [midway, above] {$u(t)$} (controller);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center), % <----
    scale=0.5,transform shape]
      \begin{axis}[
    axis lines = middle,
    xmin = 0,
    xmax = 1.1,
    ymin = -2,
    ymax = 2,
    xtick = {0,0.5,1},
    ytick = {-1.5,0,1.5},
    axis line style = thick,
    xlabel style = {right},
    % xlabel style={at=(current axis.right of origin), anchor=west},
    xlabel={\huge $t$},
    % ylabel style={at=(current axis.above origin), anchor=south},
    ylabel style={above},
    ylabel={\huge $y(t)$},
    extra y ticks = {0},
    % extra x ticks = {0},
    yticklabel style={
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        /pgf/number format/precision=4
    },
    x post scale=1.2,
    y post scale=1.2,
    clip=false
]
\addplot [
    domain=0:1,
    samples=300,
    line width = 2pt, blue
] {sin(deg(2*pi*x))};
\addplot [
    domain=0:1,
    samples=300,
    line width = 2pt, red
] {1.5*sin(deg(2*pi*(x+(1/4))))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thankyou Zarko. It is the proper way.